# What’s wrong with my recursion for finding primes? (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, primes

I’m trying to create a program that lists all the primes below an inputted number, and I came up with the code:

```
def primes():
    num = 20

    numlist = list(range(1,num+1))
    i = len(numlist)

    for j in numlist[2:]:
        ans = divisible(j,i)

        if ans:
            numlist.remove(j)
            print(numlist)

def divisible(m,n):

    if m!=n and m%n==0:
        return True

    elif n == 1:
        return False

    else:
        divisible(m, n-1)

primes()
```

(I used an in-browser IDE so the `num` part was a proxy for the input.)

My idea was to create a separate function `divisible()` that when inputted two ints, `m` and `n`, would check if `n` divides `m`. I'm not sure if I was right in my recursion, but I wrote `divisible(m,n-1)` the idea was that it would iterate through all the integers from `n` downward and it would return `True` if any `n` divided `m`, or `False` if it reached `1`.

In the main code, `m` iterated through all the numbers in a `list`, and `n` is the total number of elements in the same `list`. I put the `print(numlist)` inside the `if` statement as an error check. The problem I’m having is nothing is printing. The code returned literally nothing. Is there something I’ve missed in how recursion works here?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong here:

You've made a common beginner's recursion error in that you have a recursive function that returns a value, but when you call it recursively, you ignore the returned value.  You need to deal with it or pass it along.

It seems like this modulus is backward:

```
if ... and m%n==0:
```

Maybe it should be:

```
if ... and n % m == 0:
```

You're code doesn't appear to be calculating *primes*.  It's looks like it's calculating *relative primes* to `n`.

You start your list of numbers at `1`:

```
numlist = list(range(1,num+1))
```

But you start testing at index `2`:

```
for j in numlist[2:]:
```

Which is the number `3` and you never check the divisibility of the number `2`.

Even with all these fixes, I don't feel your algorithm will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your divisible function doesn't return anything if it falls into else part. change it as

```
def divisible(m, n):
    if m!=m and m%n==0:
        return True
    elif n==1 :
        return False
    else:
        return divisible(m,n-1)
```

This should work